# Wiring up a dynamically created LinkButton that is being inserted into a PlaceHolder that is in a ListView Item

Tags: c#, vb.net, listview, dynamic

I have a ListView that is outputting line items that each have a PlaceHolder object.
Within that PlaceHolder I am outputting any number of LinkButtons.

I am adding a Click event Handler to each Link Button to invoke a code-behind method.

HOWEVER,

The method is not being fired when the link buttons are clicked.  I need help determining why this is and how I might be able to fire a method in the code-behind when one of these Link Buttons are clicked.

I have already performed the process of storing the LinkButton controls so that they repopulate the Placeholders after a post back. (They don't disappear when clicked).

All suggestions welcomed!  Thanks!

Comment: Could you post the relevant HTML and code-behind?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a link for an example of LinkButton to review and verify your code is correct. if not helpful, copy your code to let us help you and solve  the problem.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.linkbutton(v=vs.110).aspx